# react typescript component set prop with condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to set the component's prop when the variable's value defined.
Below is my current code.

```
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'
...
interface State {
 ...
  coverFile: File | null;
  ...
}
class Test extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  state = {
    ...
    coverFile: null,
    ...
  };
...
const file = event.target.files;
self.setState({
              coverFile: file[0],
            });

<Cropper
  image={coverFile?coverFile:undefined}
  ...
/>
```

And this is the error message.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<CropperProps>): Cropper', gave the following error.
    Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CropperProps, context?: any): Cropper', gave the following error.
    Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2769)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I used react-easy-crop
```import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'```
And this is image type: ```(JSX attribute) image?: string | undefined```

Comment: Simply use `image={coverFile}`

Comment: ```Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'```

Comment: At least show the assignment of `coverFile`. That seems to be of importance

Comment: I added some code in the question, please have a check and let me know which part of code do you want more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explains your error message

> Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

`Cropper`'s image prop expects a `string` or `undefined` but you are passing `null` or `undefined`

Did you initialise `coverFile` as `null`? If so, you can set it to `undefined` to silence the error

**Update:**
If you can't figure out where the null is coming from you can simply do this:

```
<Cropper
  image={coverFile || undefined}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: The result is same.
```No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<CropperProps>): Cropper', gave the following error.
    Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CropperProps, context?: any): Cropper', gave the following error.
    Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.```

Comment: You need to post more code. How do you assign `coverFile`? It seems your `coverFile` is still `null`

Comment: Yes, at first the coverFile value is null. After open the file from the dialog, it will be set.
Which part of the code do you want?

Comment: Use `undefined` instead of `null`

Comment: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use `(JSX attribute) image?: string | undefined` you can write `image?: string` because, with strict null checks, an optional parameter automatically adds `| undefined`

Second, based on [react-easy-crop document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-easy-crop) it needs to `image` or `video` (at least one of them) to be required, so if there was an undefined image, you need to pass a valid `video` parameters I think this could help :

```
 {coverFile && (
  <Cropper
   image={coverFile}
   ...
 />)
 }
```

Comment: Please have a look at @Sohaib's answer. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The image props for Cropper stands for string. And it seems to be an error with the code as following that you mentioned.

```
<Cropper
  image={coverFile?coverFile:undefined}
  ...
/>
It would be fine by replacing it by
  <Cropper
    image={coverFile || undefined}
    ...
  />
or
  {
  image ?
  <Cropper
    image=coverFile
    ...
  /> : ''
  }
```

Hope your success